# Did Anne Boleyn's father set her and Henry the 8th up?

Tags: tudor-period

In the TV show, The Tudors, they make it seems as though Anne and Mary were meant to sleep with Henry in order to sway him away from Cardinal Wolsey who had French interests in mind. Is this true?

While I know that Mary was Henry's mistress first, I'm unclear about the context under which they met. Was it started just for political gain because of Thomas Boleyn?

Comment: No citation right now, but seems to me that in the era the bride's father would generally be central in arranging any marriage.

Comment: This wasn't an "arranged marriage" situation... Henry VIII was already married at the time.  The idea is that Thomas Boleyn intentionally pushed his daughters to catch Henry's eye and thus become mistresses.   The [history of England](https://thehistoryofengland.co.uk/2017/07/23/219-cloth-of-gold/) podcast goes into lots of detail in a very approachable manner over the course of ten or so episodes.